# Input mask on initials (microsoft access)

Tags: validation, ms-access, input-mask

Im trying to work out how to put an input mask on initials which will allow for initials that are two/three letters on.

I have tried entering >L?L< but this only allows three letter initials to be entered and not two letter initials.

Is there another symbol I should be using other than '?' that means that the user does not have to enter a character in that place?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `>LL?`

- `>` forces everything to uppercase
- `L` is a required character
- `?` is an optional character